# Spring Data Cassandra adhere Batch Limit

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Using `CassandraTemplate` in spring I get a batchOps and then insert values in a batch

```
CassandraBatchOperations batchOps = cassandraTemplate.batchOps();
batchOps.insert(listOfEntities);
batchOps.execute();
```

But inserting too many entities in 1 batch will throw an exception because of `BATCH_SIZE_FAIL_THRESHOLD_IN_KB` setting.

Using Spring data Cassandra, how do I determine the query length of the inserts before inserting them in the batch so that I don't put too many inserts (based on the `BATCH_SIZE_FAIL_THRESHOLD_IN_KB`) in 1 batch and try to insert them in multiple batches?

Comment: could you not count the size of `listofentities` right there? Also, remember that only a single-partition batches are a good use case. If you [use multi-partition batches, it will hurt the cluster's stability and performance](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/dse/docs/developing/batch/batch-bad-example.html)

Comment: @Madhavan well maybe I could manually calculate the query size for each one and iterate over listOfEntities until I reach the limit. But I was looking for a way to do it with `CassandraTemplate` and not having to calculate manually.
But as @Aaron stated, what I'm trying to do is actually futile for this use case of mine.
But I'm still intersted to play around with `CassandraTemplate` to see if it's possible to do what I wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

So when a batch statement runs in Cassandra, a node is picked as the coordinator. That node has to hold all of the batched writes in memory, and then coordinate writes with all other nodes in the cluster based on the hashed token values of the primary keys in each write.

Long story short, I've seen nodes crash because of this. That's why that batch limit exists, and why it's better when using Cassandra to *not* batch writes, but send them to the cluster one at a time.

**TL;DR;**

Do not batch writes in Cassandra; rather execute them one at a time.

**Edit 20240311**

> Just to be sure, this also happens when the batch runs only on 1 partition?

If I look at the docs for help on how batching works, I can see this:

> Single partition batching will send one message to the coordinator for all operations. All replicas for the single partition receive the data, and the coordinator waits for acknowledgement.

So a single partition batch still uses a coordinator, but the performance hit is less because of only a subset of nodes in the cluster will be required.

> Even for 1 partition inserts, you'd suggest executing one at a time?

TBH, if I was doing it, I wouldn't bother with batch; I'd do them all one-at-a-time. Especially with Spring. Spring makes it easier to do simple things. However, with more complex operations, we're stuck  with Spring's interpretation and implementation of things, which sometimes does get in the way (as you are finding out).

Comment: Just to be sure, this also happens when the batch runs only on 1 partition? Even for 1 partition inserts, you'd suggest executing one at a time?